# Avoid signed assembly network access

Tags: .net, assemblies, digital-certificate

I'm using a .net assembly that was digitally signed (using comodo), and I noticed that the first time my application loads the assembly it connects to 'ocsp.usertrust.com' and 'crl.comodoca.com'.

Is there a way to avoid these connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be automatically checking for revocation of the certificate. There's an option for this in IE - Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Security > Check For Publisher's Certificate Revocation

Answer (score 0):

It is just verifying the cert. The problem is???? Unsign the assembly, if you can, or block the port or address.

But what is the problem?